# Logon time script | how to overwrite last logon Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, authentication

I have a script configured on my GPO that tracks a certain user group their logon times exported to a csv.

Now i've gotten the question, to make it show only the LAST logon time.

At the moment it just writes down every single logon time, but they would like only the last one.

Is there a way to make it overwrite it instead?

Let's say user1 logs in 3 times, i would like to only show it the last one, and that for every user in this group.

The script i have at the moment is a very simple one:

```
"logon {0} {1} {2:DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss}" -f (Get-Date),$env:username, $env:computername >> \\server\folder\file.csv
```

Much appreciated if somebody could tell me if it is possible!

Comment: This is not a good idea, if there are a lot of records, all those problems for which the databases were invented will arise, writing to several users in one file is not good in itself.

I recommend using any database for these purposes SQLLite, MSSQL Express or any other.

Comment: There are not that many records, it's about scanner users.
And there are only about 10-15 i'd say of those. 

That's why it would be easy just to see the last logon of said scanner, and make it overwrite itself instead of adding every single logon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are appending a line to a text file which is not a CSV file because the values aren't separated by a delimiter character.
Then also, you use the wrong order of values for the `-f` Format operator: While the template string clearly has the date as the **last** placeholder in `{2:DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss}`, you feed that as the **first** value..

Please also notice that a date format is Case-Sensitive, so you need to change `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss` into `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

I'd advise to change the script you now have to something like:

```
[PsCustomObject]@{
    User      = $env:USERNAME
    Computer  = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    LogonDate = '{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date)
} | Export-Csv -Path '\\server\folder\UserLogon.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Then, when it comes down to reading that file back and preserving only the latest logons, you can do

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path '\\server\folder\UserLogon.csv' | Group-Object User | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.LogonDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)} |
               Select-Object -Last 1
}

# output on screen
$data

# overwrite the CSV file to keep only the last logons
$data | Export-Csv -Path '\\server\folder\UserLogon.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
I'm still a bit of a powershell noob, and have to learn alot.
Hope i'll get there with time.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think one arrow `>` should be to overwrite a file.

There is also a command called `Out-File` with parameters to overwrite a file.

More information on the PowerShell documentation,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

I must reiterate what others have commented about this not being the best approach to this problem however, given the output file that you have, you could process it like this to get the last record for a given user:

```
$last = @{} ; Get-Content \\server\folder\file.csv |% { $token = $_ -split ' ' ; $last.$($token[3]) = $_ }
$last
```

It creates a hash keyed with the username and updates it with the last line from the file.  You can also access `$last.foo` to get the last entry for user `foo`.

I'd also note that your CSV isn't a CSV which makes it more difficult to process.  You'd be better to use `Export-CSV` or at least putting the commas in.  Also, while still not the best approach, you could create a file per user which you could just overwrite each time they login, thus:

```
new-object  PSObject -Property @{ 'date'= (Get-Date); 'username'= $env:username; 'Computer' = $env:computername } | Export-CSV -Path "\\server\folder\$($env:username).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

You could import everything for processing by doing:

```
gci \\server\folder\*.csv  |% { import-csv $_ }
```